# Android "Clock" Source git clone, import Error

Tags: android

Cloned android source of Alarm clock from git.
imported to my eclipse found following errors:

```
Alarms.java: 
Line 463: Intent alarmChanged = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED);
Error: ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED cannot be resolved or is not a field.
---------------------------------------

AlarmKlaxon.java
Line 89: mVibrator = new Vibrator();
Error: Cannot instantiate the type Vibrator
-----------------------------------

DigitalClock.java
Line 184: CharSequence newTime = DateFormat.format(mFormat, mCalendar);
Error: Call requires API level 3 (current min is 1):android.text.format.DateFormat#format

Line 167: mContext.unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
Error: mContext cannot be resolved
-----------------------------------

SetAlarm.java
Line 115: FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()
            .findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.content);
Error:com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable

-----------------------------------
```

It is just not this application , any aplication that i clone from git android tree ... i am getting some error or the other.
I dont know what i am doing wrong .
I am targetting for jelly bean.
and i also checked making build target as google API also but no use.

Comment: I figured this out, you cannot checkout individual project and build! (I know that's stupid) instead, you have to checkout the whole tree and build from root level

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you should do:

- Start fresh, so delete that project and close Eclipse.
- Download the source again
- Open Eclipse, press `Ctrl + N`. This will open new project wizard.
- Select `Android` and then `Android Project From Existing Code`.
- Point the `Root Directory` to the DeskClock source. Consider checking `Copy projects into workspace`. This way when you edit the files, you won't edit the original source you downloaded, but the copy of it in your workspace.
- Open the `Manifest` and set a `minSdkVersion`.

It'll probably be like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

- You'll need to add the `android-support-v13` library. This can be found in the SDK.

The path will be something like this:

```
PATH_TO_YOUR_SDK\extras\android\support\v13
```

Once you have this, toss it in the `libs` folder in your project. If it isn't there, create one.

After you've done all that, you should clean your project if there are still any errors. You should also consider highlighting your project, pressing `Alt+Enter` selecting `Android` and changing the `Project Build Target` to the latest source.

Make sure you're using the right link when you clone the repo:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock
```

Also, make sure you're pointing Eclipse to the right Android SDK directory. Go to `Window` --> `Android` and make sure the `SDK Location` is pointed to the correct path.

Comment: its not working i followed your comments exactly but no use ... still the same error persist

Comment: I made some edits at the bottom about cloning the latest source and doubling checking Eclipse is set up properly.

Comment: No use ... and the source is not Deskclock its alarm clock its android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock

Comment: [In that case you'll need to follow instructions similar to these](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/using-com-android-internal-part-5-summary-and-example/). And y'know that app is deprecated, right? DeskClock replaced it. It has the same features, but much more up-to-date source.